# Using List<T> in Rust

Tags: linked-list, rust

I'm just starting in Rust and trying to write some basic algorithms to get a feel for the language.  My attempt here is to write a function that given an `int` will convert it into binary form represented by a linked list of `bool` values with `true` for `1` and `false` for `0` (if there's a better "bit" type I'm open to that suggestion as well).

My current implementation is as follows:

```
fn to_base_2(num: int) -> List<bool> {
    fn to_base_2_acc(num: int, acc: List<bool>) -> List<bool> {
        if num == 0 {
            return acc;
        } else {
            let bit = (num % 2) == 0;
            let new_acc = Cons(bit, acc);
            return to_base_2_acc(num / 2, new_acc);
        }
    }

    to_base_2_acc(num, Nil);
}
```

This code fails to compile with:

```
main.rs:20:28: 20:31 error: mismatched types: expected `@extra::list::List<bool>` but found `extra::list::List<bool>` (expected @-ptr but found enum extra::list::List)
main.rs:20              let new_acc = Cons(bit, acc);
                                                ^~~
```

However updating the code to be managed by dropping `@` in front of `List` results in the following:

```
main.rs:15:34: 15:45 error: The managed box syntax is being replaced by the `std::gc::Gc` and `std::rc::Rc` types. Equivalent functionality to managed trait objects will be implemented but is currently missing.
main.rs:15      fn to_base_2_acc(num: int, acc: @List<bool>) -> List<bool> {
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.rs:15:34: 15:45 note: add #[feature(managed_boxes)] to the crate attributes to enable
main.rs:15      fn to_base_2_acc(num: int, acc: @List<bool>) -> List<bool> {
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.rs:25:21: 25:25 error: The managed box syntax is being replaced by the `std::gc::Gc` and `std::rc::Rc` types. Equivalent functionality to managed trait objects will be implemented but is currently missing.
main.rs:25      to_base_2_acc(num, @Nil);
                                   ^~~~
main.rs:25:21: 25:25 note: add #[feature(managed_boxes)] to the crate attributes to enable
main.rs:25      to_base_2_acc(num, @Nil);
                                   ^~~~
```

This is using rustc 0.9-pre.  Do linked lists not work in this version of the compiler?

Comment: With the landing of https://github.com/mozilla/rust/pull/10576 , Gc<T> is replacing the `@` syntax, but adding #[feature(managed_boxes)] in top of your code should make that error go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `@`'s because [`extra::list::List`](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/extra/list/enum.List.html) is defined such that `Cons` requires an `@List<T>` as the second value.

However, as you found out, trying to add `@`'s throws a feature gate error. As snf commented, you can add

```
#[feature(managed_boxes)];
```

to the top of the root crate file to enable the usage of `@`.

Comment: Are "managed_boxes" an old feature going away or a new feature coming in?

Comment: @T.Stone: They're an old feature going away. They're being replaced with library types `std::gc::Gc<T>` and `std::rc::Rc<T>`.